# Nivo Slider v3.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

When we point mouse cursor on image running in slider image transition stops. How can I stop the mouse pointer effect? I need continuous image transition

Comment: This is not common behavior. Please provide an example.

Answer (score 3):

You need to to change the below default settings to false, you can change it like below

e.g:

```
  $('#yourElement').nivoSlider({pauseOnHover: false});
```

More here:

[nivo-slider docs](http://dev7studios.com/nivo-slider/#/documentation)